# toFixed returning wrong output

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function get_tax(rent) {
    var pcharges = parseFloat($('#pcharges').val());
    pcharges = pcharges.toFixed(2);
    rent = parseFloat(rent);
    rent = rent.toFixed(2);

    var tax = parseFloat((rent * 15) / 100);
    tax = tax.toFixed(2);

    $('#tax').val(tax);
    var tot_rent = pcharges + rent + tax;
    // alert(tot_rent);
    $('#tot_rent').val(tot_rent);
    // alert(tax);

}

function get_total(pcharges) {
    pcharges = parseFloat(pcharges);
    old_tot = parseFloat($('#tot_rent').val());
    // alert(pcharges+old_tot);
    $('#tot_rent').val(pcharges + old_tot);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Rent:<input required onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');" onchange="get_tax(this.value)" type="text" name="rent">
Tax:<input required onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');" id="tax" type="text" name="tax">
Phone Charges:<input value="0" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');" required id="pcharges"  onchange="get_total(this.value)" type="text" name="pcharges">
Total Rent:<input required onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');" id="tot_rent" type="text" name="tot_rent">
```

i want to get rent from user and show 15% of it in tax and user will put phone charges manually and then i need to add rent,tax,phone charges. tax is coming properly but total rent is not coming properly

Comment: `.toFixed()` returns a string, not a number. So your subsequent `+` operator is doing string concatenation. You should be doing all the calculations with numbers and then `.toFixed` to display the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add string value (`toFixed()` returns the string) which is concatenating the values, use the unary plus(+) to convert to float and then perform addition.

```js
function get_tax(rent) {
    var pcharges = parseFloat($('#pcharges').val());
    pcharges = +pcharges.toFixed(2);
    rent = parseFloat(rent);
    rent = +rent.toFixed(2);

    var tax = parseFloat((rent * 15) / 100);
    tax = +tax.toFixed(2);

    $('#tax').val(tax);
    var tot_rent = pcharges + rent + tax;
    // alert(tot_rent);
    $('#tot_rent').val(tot_rent);
    // alert(tax);

}

function get_total(pcharges) {
    pcharges = parseFloat(pcharges);
    old_tot = parseFloat($('#tot_rent').val());
    // alert(pcharges+old_tot);
    $('#tot_rent').val(pcharges + old_tot);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Rent:<input required onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');" onchange="get_tax(this.value)" type="text" name="rent">
Tax:<input required onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');" id="tax" type="text" name="tax">
Phone Charges:<input value="0" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');" required id="pcharges"  onchange="get_total(this.value)" type="text" name="pcharges">
Total Rent:<input required onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');" id="tot_rent" type="text" name="tot_rent">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `.toFixed()` returns the `string` value. so if you add multiple `string` values it will concatenate so

change

```
 var tot_rent = pcharges + rent + tax;
```

To

```
var tot_rent = var tot_rent = parseFloat( pcharges) + parseFloat(rent) + parseFloat(tax);
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/oetsuv7k/1/)